# git reports fatal error because object is too large

Tags: git, file, github, gitlab, filesystems

I am new to git and have already messed something up.
I created an empty git repo and inserted files there. Among these files, there were some big files (movies with > 1 GB size). I commited them and there was no problem (`ca8d0e1 HEAD@{2}: commit: Status am 27.02.2024`). Then, I made a mistake. I removed some files (also the movies) and committed the changes. Or did I remove the commit? I am not sure, therefore the output of `git reflog` below.
I have then looked at ways to get to my data again.
I have used `git reflog`:

```
> git reflog
eda6237 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit: added gitignore
6d0c8ba (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 6d0c8ba0b339426173d04a2c4676ff5d3db8b4d3 [1fd5502251ec0eb7a17e8dbe7b4bd73514881572]
ca8d0e1 HEAD@{2}: commit: Status am 27.02.2024
6d0c8ba (origin/main, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{3}: clone: from https://git.uibk.ac.at/csaw1192/bachelorarbeit.git
>
```

The commit I want to go back to is `ca8d0e1 HEAD@{2}: commit: Status am 27.02.2024`.
I therefore wanted to got back to this commit to repair the damage I had done. I found out that `git reset` was the right command. But the result is the following:

```
> git reset --hard ca8d0e1
fatal: object too large to read on this platform: 15531648537 is cut off to 2646746649
>
```

Now, some of my data is back, but there is also data missing (not only the movies, but all movies are missing).

I don't know what to do and how to get back my data.
If it is not possible to get back my data, is there at least a possibility to get back the file structure I had?

Thanks for your help and bye,
moinmoin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove/delete a large file from the commit history in the Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-can-i-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-the-commit-history-in-the-git-reposito)

Comment: Unfortunately not.
When I for example use the garbage collector, I get:

`> git gc
Enumerating objects: 593, done.
fatal: object too large to read on this platform: 15531648537 is cut off to 2646746649
fatal: failed to run repack
> `

Could it be that something is wrong with the repo because I put in too large files?

Comment: Also the filecheck does not seem to work: `> git fsck --full
fatal: object too large to read on this platform: 15531648537 is cut off to 2646746649
> `